# Angular Material DatePicker - Error: MdDatepicker: No provider found for DateAdapter

Tags: angular, angular-material

Following Material docs, I:

```
import {MdDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material';
```

in root module and added it in providers list, but coudln't use it in template. Got this error:

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: MdDatepicker: No provider found for
>   DateAdapter. You must import one of the following modules at your
>   application root: MdNativeDateModule, or provide a custom
>   implementation.

So according to it, I removed last import and added:

```
import {MdNativeDateModule} from '@angular/material';
```

And now, looks like, it works. Why Material docs tells to import `MdDatepickerModule`, but not `MdNativeDateModule`? And how they differ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[The example in the docs](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples) actually does import `MdNativeDateModule`. Click on the plunker link and see the main.ts file. The docs are not as clear about this as would be preferred.

`MdDatepickerModule` is the module containing the component itself. The component is agnostic to which implementation of dates you use with it.

For example, if you wished to use [Moment.JS dates](https://momentjs.com/docs/) instead of JavaScript's native `Date` objects, you could write your own class to work with Moment.JS objects. This is explained [here](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#choosing-a-date-implementation-and-date-format-settings).

If you simply want to work with JavaScript's `Date` objects, though, you would need to use the `NativeDateAdapter` class that is already included in `@angular/material`. This class is provided by the `MdNativeDateModule`.

It is not provided by `MdDatepickerModule` since that module deals only with the UI component, and in case you were using Moment.JS objects, you would have no need for the `NativeDateAdapter` class in your application.

Comment: for update the module name is now - "MatNativeDateModule"

Comment: whats the difference between MatNativeDateModule and MatMomentDateModule?

Comment: @Maurice they're for working with JS' native Date objects and Moment.js objects repectively

Comment: @AakashJain seems the `MatMomentDateModule` isnt available out-of-the-box, do you need to install Moment.js first?

Comment: @galki check [here](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#choosing-a-date-implementation-and-date-format-settings) for how to import the module. You will need moment.js in your project as well.

Answer (score 6):

you need to import `MatNativeDateModule` from `@angular/material` once you imported, you should have to import and export it in `@NgModule` you can see on [angular material](https://stackblitz.com/angular/roggryjarnb?file=main.ts)